# What is the mathematical notation for Convex Hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, convex-analysis

I've been scanning through scientific papers, this site and just googling for it, but I can't find a commonly accepted notation for the convex hull.

So my question is; if there is, what is the standard notation for convex hull?

Seems to me people just use their favorite out of a large collection of notations (or invent their own notation) to denote the convex hull of, say $S$, including
\begin{align}
\mathrm{conv}(S),\ \mathrm{CH}(S),\ \mathrm{conv.hull}(S),\ \mathrm{Co}(S),\ \mathrm{C}(S),
\end{align}

which I find frustrating. :)

Comment: What about $\operatorname{co} S$?

Comment: I happen to like conv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the notation used in an article is set by the author who is somewhat obliged to use standard notations (as prescribed by any recognized publisher) unless the document has become so notationally heavy that certain things must be avoided. Conv$\,(\cdot)$ fairly standard for the convex hull as it does not interfere much with other potential notations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll stick with $\mathrm{Conv}(\cdot)$ then. It's indeed not likely to suffer from notational confusion with other meanings. Plus I find it the most logical/suitable. Nevertheless I find it weird that there is no clear consensus on the notation, like there is on symbols like $\sum$.

Comment: This is likely because things like summation $\Sigma$ and product $\prod$ are arithmetical notation and are symbols representing the very essence of mathematics.

Comment: Haha, yes that is true. Having no widely accepted notation for a summation seems terrible; people using multiple notations for convex hull seems overcomeable.

Answer (score 3):

I am used to the notation $\operatorname{Conv}(\cdot)$, but you can really use whatever you like as long as you explain the notation.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen $\mathrm{Hull}(\cdot)$ used pretty often; I think Michael Kapovich uses it in his papers. Unless there's another usage of hull in mathematics that I'm not aware of, it's a pretty safe and easy to understand notation.